# Function not ending after returning

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following function where I cannot figure out, why it will not stop after returning when the condition `depth > 0` is no longer met:

```
depth = 5

def traverse(target, depth):
    try:
        result = callAddress(target)
        inner_transaction_targets = analyseTransaction(result)
        traversed_addresses = compileAddresses(compiled_receiver_addresses, inner_transaction_targets)
        if depth > 0:
            for inner in inner_transaction_targets:
                traverse(inner, depth - 1)
                print('Starting analysis of child address {} at depth {}.'.format(inner, max_depth))
        else:
            return traversed_addresses 
    except:
        print('Could not traverse.')
```

As soon as the depth reaches 0, the script jumps to

```
else:
    return traversed_addresses
```

However from there, instead of stopping execution it jumps to

```
print('Starting analysis of child address {} at depth {}.'.format(inner,max_depth))
```

and adds +1 to `depth` and recommences the `for inner in inner_transaction_targets` loop. I cannot find where in the script it would specify this behaviour.

Comment: You are specifying this behavior by calling `traverse` recursively...

Comment: @mkrieger1 that is indeed intended, I want the function to execute recursively. However the recursive executions should stop once depth reaches 0.. Any ideas how this can be structured better?

Comment: As soon as you `return`, execution will continue after the call to `traverse` for each recursion, so it will print and continue looping. This is what you have written. Maybe you'd rather want to use iteration instead?

Comment: Try switching the two lines `traverse(inner, depth-1)` and `print('Starting analysis blahblah')` so that the `print` is executed **before** the recursive call. Then replace the line `traverse(inner, depth-1)` with `return traverse(inner, depth-1)` so that the function actually returns after the recursive call.

Comment: @Stef that actually worked, thanks so much!